# How to write custom extension for google maps in a clean way

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to write a small extension for google maps API, which I'm going to use often in my webpages. The question is:

1. I will write one main object. In which object shall I embed it - in `google.maps`? How? Like in jquery we use `$.fn.extend` to extend the jQuery object, how can this be cleanly done in google maps?
2. There should be one instance of the object per one `google.maps.Map` object. I need to create my object when `google.maps.Map` is created (also, constructor of my object requires `google.maps.Map` object as parameter). How should I do it in a clean way?

Please point me to the relevant documentation if any. I tried to look at the [Google Maps API Reference](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html), but without success.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very basic example for extending the google.maps.Map object. Note this is just a function you can call on the created google.maps.Map instance

**update**
now with custom object (for the example I used `new Array()`)

```
if (!google.maps.Map.prototype.myNewFunction) {
        google.maps.Map.prototype.myObject = new Array();

        google.maps.Map.prototype.myNewFunction = function(paramA, paramB) {
                // this = the google.maps.Map
                console.log("paramA: " + paramA);
                console.log("paramB: " + paramB);

                // if you want to return you're object
                return this.myObject;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel, but where do I put my object data?